# Changing to Comparison Operator

Tags: php

I was told that the previous code wasn't using parameters even when employing a library that supports it. And that I was using  an assignment operator rather than a comparison. Also the true branch is redudant.

Previous Code:

```
if ($profilepic = $row['profilepic']){
    $profilepic = $row['profilepic'];
}else{
    $profilepic = "DamjuNoImage";
}
```

Current Code:

```
$profilepic = $row['profilepic'];
$noimage = "DamjuNoImage";

if ($profilepic != $row['profilepic']){
        echo $noimage;
    }
```

I wanted to double check to see if I fixed the code even though I already tested it.

Comment: You need to go back to learning the fundamentals. It should be eye-popping obvious that in the current version the `if` block will never do anything. It's also almost certain that the code does not do what you intend it to (because what it actually does, does not make sense).

Comment: When I tested it, the current code did what I intend it to do.

Comment: @taeja87 What do you *intend* it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following:

```
$profilepic = $row['profilepic'];
if ($profilepic != $row['profilepic']){
    echo $noimage;
}
```

Your if-statement will never do anything. The first line makes `$profilepic` equal to `$row['profilepic']` (whether that's an empty string, null, or what-have-you), and the condition checks if they are not equal - which will never be the case since you just finished making them equal.

If you want to provide a default image, do something like this:

```
if ( empty( $row["profilepic"] ) ) {
    $profilepic = $row["profilepic"];
} else {
    $profilepic = "DamJuNoImage";
}
```

Or written more concisely:

```
// Assign value of column if not empty, otherwise "DamJuNoImage"
$profilepic = empty( $row["profilepic"] ) 
    ? "DamJuNoImage" 
    : $row["profilepic"];
```

If the profile pic column is empty, we assign the a default value to `$profilepic`. From there we can just echo our image.

```
echo "<img src='{$profilepic}' />";
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/KXuQyVma

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use the more concisely one.

Comment: @taeja87 I made an important change to that part; please use the updated version.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Learned something new.